# Let $X$ and $Y$ random variables, $\{X_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$, and $\{Y_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ samples. Is $\{(X_{1},Y_{1})\}_{i=1}^{n}$ a sample of $Z=(X,Y)$?

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, random-variable, sample

Let $X$ and $Y$ two random variables with dnsity distribution function $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ respectivelly. We assume  that $(X,Y)$ is a random variable on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ where 
$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A)=\iint_{A}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)dxdy. \tag{*}$$

Let $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$, and  $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n} $ samples of $X$ and $Y$ respectivelly.

**The question:** Is $(X_{1},Y_{1}),\ldots,(X_{n},Y_{n})$ a sample of random variable $Z=(X,Y)$?

If the answer is negative, how from $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$, and  $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n} $  I generate a sample of the random variable $Z=(X,Y)$?

Comment: It depends what notation you mean for $(X,Y)$. If it is just a pairing, then yes. But if you mean the joint distribution, unless $X,Y$ are independent, the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ depends on the sampling scheme and so naively sampling $X$ first, and then $Y$, then putting them together do not give you a sample from the joint distribution.

Comment: @user321627 The distribution of $(X,Y)$ is given by (*),  in this case, is it a pairing?.

Comment: It appears that it is not. The expression you have is an expression for the joint distribution. If you were to sample from $X$, and then sample from $Y$, you would essentially get the elements inside the integral. However, you would still need the integration on the outside. Hence, unless $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and possibly for some other trivial cases, you can't sample from $X$ and $Y$ separately and get a combined sample converging to the integral you have. Depending on what problem it is, you may be well informed to look at Gibbs Samplers.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2648120/). That is against SE & wastes a lot of people's time. Pick the site you want to ask on & delete the other version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted to [math.SE].

Answer (score 4):

The reasoning in the comments is misleading. If 
$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A)=\iint_{A}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)dxdy \tag{*}$$for every $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, then since by definition
$$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A)=\iint_{A}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy,$$
we have $f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. So $X$ and $Y$ are independent, meaning that $(X_1,Y_1),\dots,(X_n,Y_n)$ does indeed constitute an i.i.d. sample of the random vector $Z = (X,Y)$.

Comment: To extend your argument a little bit, one can essentially construct a multivariate distribution of arbitrary dimensions from univariate rv's given that $(^*)$ holds.

Comment: This answer is ambiguous to the point of having the potential to be badly misinterpreted. Suppose your "bijective pairing" of the samples were to associate the $i^\text{th}$ highest of the $X_i$ with the $i^\text{th}$ highest of the $Y_i$ for each $i$: would $(X_1,Y_1)\ldots, (X_n,Y_n)$ really be a sample of $Z$??

Comment: @whuber Thanks for pointing that out! I now think that I was attempting a level of generality in my answer that is not actually useful in this context. I have revised my answer accordingly.